# Can I usefully control an electric baseboard heater in 1 room with the same thermostat as my central heat?

Tags: hvac, heating, thermostat, central-heating

My house has a gas furnace and heat pump (and AC). Unfortunately, one bedroom does not have air ducts hooked up. Is there a way I could install a baseboard heater in that bedroom and have it controlled by the same thermostat that controls the furnace and heat pump? The answer could be wired as 1 zone or 2.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good idea to me. Not only would it be more complicated to do -- involving relays and more wiring -- than a thermostat in the room, but it wouldn't work as well either. Unless the baseboard heater heats the room at exactly the same speed as the furnace/heat pump heats the rest of the house (hint: it won't -- especially with no air flow) you'll end up with a room that is either too cold or too hot most of the time.

Comment: One relay, commodity device, not too hard.  You're right, sizing will be a trick.  Could "test it out" by initially switching a 120V outlet, and plugging portable heaters in there til you found the right wattage.

Comment: When you're wiring in that baseboard heater, why not add its own thermostat?

Comment: @Harper It's not the relay way is "hard", it's just more work than a stand-alone thermostat (especially a wireless one), it's more complex (more things to go wrong), more expensive (relay, additional wiring) *and* it will not be as good (as far as room temp is concerned). All downsides, no upsides.

Comment: To add to the reasons not to do so, consider where the thermostat is physically located. It's not in the bedroom so it'll never get the temperature correct there.    BTW,  the **root cause** solution is to run ducting to that bedroom.  Slightly more work and cost :-)

Comment: Probable answer: remote control.  Integrate with the Nest so you can turn it on or off from your phone in Mumbai.   Also if in-room thermostat control is so important for electric, why is it unimportant for forced air?

Comment: Thanks for all the input! Thinking about this more, I think you guys are right that an in-room thermostat would be a better result and easier. (proper feedback loop on the temperature.)

As for doing it "right" with ducting- it's particularly hard here because the furnace is in the basement. This room is upstairs. There isn't a good run of wall to have a new duct run up.